# Use `height:100%` when parents div have only min-height

Tags: html, css

Use `height:100%` when parents div have only min-height.

```
.line {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.main {
  min-height:200px;
}

<div class="col-6">
<div class=line>
</div>
<div class="col-6 main">
set by min-width
</div>
```

Using `height:100%` doesn't work when parents doesn't have height.

In this case, heights of `main` div changed depending on the amount of contents.

Because it has only `min-height`;

So, `height:100%` of `line` class doesn't work.

Is there a way to solve??

Comment: but to start with, your `.line` will have `200px` height, so what is the issue? and clearly `.main` is not the parent as well.

Comment: if it's only to draw a line consider border, box-shadow, background, pseudo element, etc

Answer (score 1):

Consider using flex to do this.
As I understand, you want your line to fill your parent div while main class takes up at least 200px?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}

.fill {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

.line {
  flex-grow: 0;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content-with-more-than-200px-height {
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="fill">
  
  </div>
  <div class="line">
   <div class="content-with-more-than-200px-height">
     contents
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```